# How can I log in my alteon2424?

Tags: networking, login, switch, serial-port, load-balancer

[image: alteon2424]I was given an old alteon 2424.

Pluging a serial cable on the console port allows me to see it booting.

I can choose at boot between 2 images in nvram by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>.

Both images talk about radius login.

I tried to log in using admin/forgetMe! without success.

How can I log in or reset factory default?

**Update :**

Had no luck with user boot :

```
Enter radius username: boot
Enter radius password:
RADIUS server timeout.
boot: Sorry.
```

Is there a physical way to reset nvram?

**Update 2:**

Found a reset button on the mainboard. Unfotunately, it just reboots the alteon without restoring factory default.

**Update 3:**

Hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> while booting enables entering "Development Mode", but it leads to the same "Enter radius username:". Using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> at boot time does not provide any improvement (some [ebay vendors](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Nortel-Alteon-2424-SSL-Switch-Load-Balancer-EB1412006-/150654644771?) suggests it leads to factory reset).

**Update 4:**

Searched the web and the main board for a way to reset it to factory default without success.

**Update 5:**

Hitting ctrl + c + f +t at boot time leads to this :

```
Loading Image:

Alteon Application Switch 2424
Rebooted because of software PANIC.
Booting complete  9:31:36 Sat Apr 13, 2013:
  Version 21.0.4 from FLASH image1, active config block.


Enter radius username:
Booting ........................................
fgrep: /proc/filesystems: No such file or directory
grep: /proc/mounts: No such file or directory
grep: /proc/mounts: No such file or directory
/etc/init.d/rcS: [: =: unary operator expected
grep: /proc/cmdline: No such file or directory
cat: /proc/cmdline: No such file or directory
sed: can't read tmpfile: No such file or directory
sed: can't read tmpfile: No such file or directory
sed: can't read tmpfile: No such file or directory
sed: can't read tmpfile: No such file or directory
sed: can't read tmpfile: No such file or directory
start-stop-daemon: nothing in /proc - not mounted?

Development Mode

Don't seem to be have all the variables for eth0/inet.
bash-2.04#
```

**Update 6:**

I guess I bricked it : I don't have the images and now it won't boot.

```
bash-2.04# flashboot
Erase Boot Region 0xfff00000Erase Total 2 Units
Performing Flash Erase of length 65536 at offset 0xf10000 done
Write Boot Region 0xfff00000dd: opening `cheetahChtboot.img': No such file or directory
bash-2.04# flashkernel
Erase Kernel Region 0xfff30000Erase Total 8 Units
Performing Flash Erase of length 65536 at offset 0xfa0000 done
Write Kernel Region 0xfff30000dd: opening `cheetahVmlinux.img': No such file or directory
bash-2.04# flashimage1
Erase Image1 Region 0xff800000Erase Total 64 Units
Performing Flash Erase of length 65536 at offset 0xbf0000 done
Write Image1 Region 0xff800000dd: opening `cheetahWebOS.img': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you log in via the console port with user 'boot' and password 'ForgetMe'?  (That should clear old passwords, followed by a tftp reinstallation and then you can log in as admin).

Comment: still looking for a way to reset nvram

Comment: No luck with **boot* rather than admin?

Comment: boot : No . *boot : Did not test. Do I need a star in the login?

Comment: No, the manual just suggested the boot and ForgetMe as factory reset passwords.

Comment: Is it possible that a radius server was previously configured for auth and it makes boot/ForgetMe unusable?

Comment: Yes. Radius is a way to centrally manage authenthication. Unless uou also got the computer running the radius server you regular authenthication will fail. However one would presume there would be a emergency hard reset exception.

Comment: Is there anymore information I can provide about this question? I'm starting running out of ideas on how to make this alteon work

Comment: This might not be the answer you expected: Ask the person who gave it to you to reset the password to a known local password?

Comment: The person who gave it to me does not know the local password (it was not the network administrator).

Comment: Did you try pressing the reset button for 30 seconds?

Comment: yes i did try without sucess

Comment: I found reference to log in with user `admin` and password `forgetMe!` - but it may well be that when radius is configured you'll have to try and contact Nortel/Radware (or whoever feels responsible) customer support.

Comment: Just to be clear, holding the reset button down, disconnecting the power (5-10 sec), then reconnecting the power, all while holding the reset button for another 30 seconds does not clear the NVram?

Comment: No, it does not clear the NVram. But question was updated and can be closed